# Django - split large model using FormWizard

Tags: django, django-forms

I am a python/django newbie trying to accomplish the task below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.
I have a model with around 50 or so fields. I need to break them up and provide a wizard like functionality.

class ABC(models.Model):
   field_1 = models.IntegerField('Field 1')
   field_2 = models.CharField('Field 2')
   ..
   ..
   field_50 =

Now in my view I create several forms with a subset of the fields like so

```
class WizardPage1(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        return cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model =  ABC
        fields = ('field_1', 'field_2', 'etc')


class WizardPage2(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

        return cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model =  ABC
        fields = ('field_11', 'field_12', 'etc')
```

When I create a FormWizard with say 5 forms, 5 records get stored.  My question is how do I save this into one record?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will definitely check out the suggestion. The 50 field have to be there because the application is a questionnaire and I cannot think of any way to split the fields. Any or all of the 50 fields may have data and I have no way of splitting that into several tables. 
Thangs again for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in your form definitions, but in how you are calling them.  When you call `WizardPage2`, you need to pass in the instance of your model which was saved by `WizardPage1`, so that it is operating on the proper object.

Also, your model should almost definitely be split into several tables.  I can't think of an well-designed object complex enough in itself to need 50 fields.  Look for separate areas of functionality, and separate them out into other models.  It will make your life easier.

Comment: Yes and yes, especially the second part. If you've got a model with 50 fields, you've either got a number of objects tied into one model or one model that should be using one-to-many fields.